# I only want the summation, but it's not working

Tags: python

The problem is: Write a Python code of a program that adds all numbers that are multiples of both 7 and 9 up to 600 (including 600)

Here's what I did:

```
summ = 0
for i in range(1, 601):
    if i % 7 == 0 and i % 9 == 0:
        summ+=i
        print(summ)
```

**Output:**

```
63
189
378
630
945
1323
1764
2268
2835
```

I want the addition. What are those numbers above 2835 for? I just want the result 2835. How do I do this?

Comment: This can be done pretty easily as a one-liner using [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
summ = 0
for i in range(1, 601):
    if i % 7 == 0 and i % 9 == 0:
        summ+=i
print(summ)
```

instead, that is, moving the `print(summ)` statement outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that indentation in Python indicates "nesting". In other words, when you indent a line, it is "inside" the construct that has less indentation. In this case, you see the running total as each number is added in because you indented the `print()` inside the `for` loop. If you only want the `print()` to happen once, pull it out of the for loop.